# Tablix cells width issue in SSRS

Tags: ssrs, ssrs-2008

I have a weird issue in the reports that I have created in SSRS 2008.

On the report I have got a number of tablixes defined, that should be displayed attached together vertically. Imagine they form a big table which each row (or set of rows) of this imaginary table has got different number of columns.

Using the alignment and width icons, I make these tablixes width the same. In design mode all these tablixes look nicely attached to each other with the same width, however when I run the report, the width of them appear unequal! I don't have any margin or padding set for them and can't understand why what I see in design mode is not consistent with what is displayed in run (review) mode!

Any idea?

Thank you.

Comment: This belongs @ Stack Overflow with a Reporting Services tag. (I don't have the rep to do that myself.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it looked ok in design mode and the issue was happening at run time, it would be helpful to investigate what elements displayed in the Tablix can grow or expand at run time.

I resolved this issue by following the steps below:

1- There was an image in one of the tablixe cells, I checked to see what is the selected option for displaying the image, if its size is bigger than the cell's size. The image had set to accept the growth, so it was increasing the width of the cell and consequently the Tablix size.

2- The padding for all cells of the row needs to be checked, especially it can be simply overlooked when an image has been assigned to a cell in the Tablix. If there is a padding, it would affect the cell size and eventually the row size in the Tablix.

I hope this description helps anyone else experience this issue.